# Docker K8s optimize images to reduce load time

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

We have a lot docker images that we need to upload to k8s, it works however when we start a new node this process can take a lot of time.

We try to change the images to use  "multi-stage" builds however still this process take a lot of time and we didn't saw significant change on the start time on new node.

Now we try the following: (however we not sure how much impact we will see ...)

1. Try (as much as we can) to use the **same docker images** `from` , example all the images
   which use alpine to use the exact same version (3.11) and not some of using version `3.10` and some `3.10.1` and some `3.11` etc , this will prevent the reuse mechanism of docker to layers that already cashed ...
2. Reduce the layers numbers , with combining the `RUN` commands to one instead of many.(we need to do it for many docker files...) , not sure how docker mechanism will help here to achieve our goals

All this process to change both of using the same version and reduce layers can take a lot of time to do, are we are wasting our time or there or this is something that can reduce the load time ? is there any other idea which may help us ?

We have many docker images based on Golang, NodeJS, java, etc.

Comment: Do you have a more specific example of something that's too large?  Looking at SO questions the most frequent thing I see is leaking a build toolchain into the final image (which multi-stage builds help); if size matters above all else, rewrite your application in a compiled language (C++, Go, Rust) and build single-binary images.

Comment: @Ivan - thanks, we already using multi stage builds whenever we can, we have golang images based on alpine and also node based on Debian etc , many dockers. so we try to consolidate them via providing base image which many of them will reuse ..., regard docker slim we saw this already however it looks like that it shrink all the layers to one layer which for some of our case it can be risky...

Comment: @DavidMaze - Thanks, we dont have any specific cases :) as we are having multiple docker images, some based on `golang` some on `node` and some `c` and `java` ...we are using for example for go a multistage build etc... after deep  investigation on our cluster load show that the most of the time is wasted on the extract of docker and not on the network, any idea how to improve that ?

Comment: Have you checked this article on [Digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/building-optimized-containers-for-kubernetes)?

Comment: @DawidKruk - thanks looking into it :)

Comment: If extraction is the slowest part, you definitely need to improve IO, faster disks, bigger fs caches, maybe storage-optimized instances if it's in the cloud. See if RAM is enough, cause if not, you might be getting a lot of swap operations which are slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so you are on the correct track

- use minimum layer
- reuse layers
- use same from tag to cache layers
- use alpine or slim images
- use multi-stage build

I think you can not reduce size further. Just try [docker squash](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-squash) but this will not help much.

So how you can boot your nodes faster?

- is it possible to bake node image with the required image layers inside it?
- is it possible to set up a docker registry next to your nodes? so that it will pull image faster without network lags
- is it possible to keep libraries outside image and mount libraries at runtime? (eg. if your code is nodejs code, keep npm's outside of the container and mount npms directory at runtime)
- k8s can run other than docker images. like [cri-o](https://cri-o.io/). is it possible for you to build cri-o images? they are lightweight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 1. Can you please elaborate how we can do it? (bake node image) as we dont know which new node we will get when we need to scale our tools.

Comment: reared 2. we try using nexus however the time was slower with it :(

Comment: regard 3 . do you mean node_modules folder without doing npm install, is it a good practice (sorry if I didnt understand it right...)

Comment: regard 4 . we will look into it , does it require new installation on k8s or it's coming out of the box ? and we just need to adjust our dockerfile to something new...

Comment: regard 1, prebake node images that contain at least your base docker images. Yes, you don't know which images/containers assigned to which nodes, at least base images will available faster.

Comment: regard 2, I am helpless :P check network setting, are images coming from some proxies? BTW, images are just files, you can create tar ball out of it. If you have some fast file server, you can pull tarball and extract image at runtime. some scripting will need

Comment: regards 3 I am not sure, Just a thought, I can surely say for ruby gems. You dont need to do updates each time. after all npm/gems are files just a matter how you load this

Comment: regards 4, Need to change k8s node settings, and need to add node selectors in deployment so that docker container can go to docker nodes and cri-o containers can go to cri-o nodes. There are many pros and cons of cri-o. also there are many ways to build cri-o images